# Multi-series Stacked Bar in SSRS

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Is it possible to have multiple series of stacked bars in SQL Server Reporting Services.

So in effect, a group within a group?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Groups are hierarchical by nature in defining a report; within a Table, Group 1 will form groups from the raw query results, and then Group 2 will be a subgroup of Group 1 by default. You can specify the order in which groups are applied in the properties of the table.

The groups defined for nested List data regions also allow for nested subgroups. Data shown in List 2, which is contained in List 1, is grouped according to specs of both lists, so a single repetition of list2's controls will be an intersection of both groups' definitions. Say List 1 groups invoices by customer ID, then List 2 groups by month/year; a single set of List2 data will show invoices for one month of one year for one customer, and its aggregates will be based on that data.